# Fine-grained access control S3 (combining user and service role policies)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am working on a system that allows users to access, process and retrieve S3 data by making HTTP requests to AWS API Gateway which invokes an AWS Lambda function. A S3 path can be a parameter to these requests. I'm trying to find an IAM native solution that will evaluate the fine-grained S3 permission (assigned to my users) with the lambda service role to determine object/bucket level access at runtime.

[Similar to what is depicted here (AWS QuickSight)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/introducing-amazon-quicksight-fine-grained-access-control-over-amazon-s3-and-amazon-athena/)

Comment: What is a question?

Comment: Is it possible to combine S3 policies from an IAM user with a service role at runtime? (without writing my own security layer). Or can I propagate the IAM user identify used to call the apigateway to my downstream resources (e.g. lambdas) so they run as the calling user (and so have the fine grained S3 permissions applied to that user and not the service role)?

This feels like quite a common thing to do but I don't see how to use IAM to achieve it.

Comment: I still don't understand what the problem is and what you want to achieve. We can assign IAM role to Lambda that has proper permissions to use S3.

Comment: When accessing S3 from a lambda, using its role, I don't have fine-grained access control. The fine-grained access is set as IAM policies on my users. For example, each user may have access to a different bucket. But currently users can use the lambda's role to access objects in S3 they do not have direct access to. I would like someway for IAM/S3 to take the intersection of what the lambda can access and what a given user can access (without coding it myself because I would lose the guarantee of security).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

API Gateway will trigger an AWS Lambda function. The Lambda function is assigned an IAM Role, which is independent of "who" made the call.

You will need to incorporate permission restrictions into the Lambda function as code. (Eg lookup user, determine what they can do, then decide what calls to make on their behalf.)

Comment: Thanks! We are looking at a solution involving STS assume-role.

Comment: If you want the users to directly call an AWS service (eg DynamoDB), you can create temporary credentials that gives them limited access to AWS services. Alternatively, they can call your application (eg via an API) and your application can determine what access they should have, then perform operations on their behalf.